# What kind of shader for 2D games (ie. Super Mario)

Tags: 2d, glsl, sprite, opengl-es-2.0

I've been trying to figure out how to use OpenGL ES 2.0 for 2D. So far I think I have a handle on most things.  But the one thing that I haven't figured out is what to do for the shaders?

I understand that you set up the camera/view and the lights in the shader, but I don't want shadows or any kind of sign of lighting.  Basically I just want to move sprites around the screen and have the sprites look exactly like they did when I drew them in photoshop.

Anyone have an example of a shader that would do this?  Or maybe an article that talks about this?

I already find that there's a lot of 3d overhead in OpenGL when trying to make a purely 2D program, but apparently it's the only viable option on Android.

Comment: This is a GLSL shader. Lighting, cameras, etc don't happen unless you *make* them happen. If you want to write exactly the texel colors, then fetch them from the texture and write them to the fragment shader output. Are you asking how to do that? Because that's trivially easy.

Comment: Actually you don't have to use OpenGL on Android to make 2d platform games. Meganoid and Stardash are both made by just using the Canvas class according to the developer. He shares a few tricks in this post: http://techblog.orangepixel.net/2012/01/android-canvas-and-gamecode-tricks/

Comment: @NicolBolas Yeah, that's what I'm asking.  So... how do you do it?

Comment: A nice alternative to using GL ES for 2D Android Games is also PelyaSDL, a very nicely done SDL port for Android - I used it for porting some games (like JA2) from desktop to android. Sound, input, scaling, etc. works just as in SDL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made a 2D videogame and these are the shaders I used. Two very simple shaders. Is this what you asking for?

```
**VERTEX_SHADER_2D =**    
   attribute vec4 position;
   attribute vec2 textureCoordIn;
   varying vec2 vTextureCoordOut;

   uniform mediump mat4 modelViewMatrix;

   void main()
      {
          gl_Position = modelViewMatrix * position;
          vTextureCoordOut = textureCoordIn;
      }


**FRAGMENT_SHADER_2D =** 
      varying mediump vec2 vTextureCoordOut;

      uniform sampler2D sampler;

      void main()
      {
          gl_FragColor = texture2D(sampler, vTextureCoordOut);
      }
```