# Game development using OpenGL ES 2.0 and C

Tags: opengl-es-2.0

I wanted to develop a game. I want to develop with the knowledge that I am having in OpenGL ES 2.0 and C language.

First thing that comes into my mind is how to develop textures etc. So please can any one tell me what are all the tools, game engine etc what all i need.

Any good tutorials for the same.

thanks in advance.

Comment: A difficult question because it's not very clear- what parts do you want to develop? Are you wanting to write your own engine or use someone else's? That affects the answer strongly. Textures and models are usually created in third party tools like Blender and Gimp, but you might choose to have your own editors or generators. Maybe you could get a better idea of where to start by reading around here: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @glenatron I want to develop the full game. I don't what is game engine and jut game. I want to develop this game http://www.albinoblacksheep.com/games/bloxorz in OpenGL ES 2.0 . how to do this . I have very less knowledge on this game engines stuff . please do help me.

Comment: You need to read around the area, then- go through some basic game development tutorials and get an idea of what is involved in creating one. That gamedev link above has lots of tutorial related questions on it, so that is the place to start, no question.

Comment: You may look at http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/. But I guess even there you might get problems with such an overly broad "what do to make game"-question.

Comment: @glenatron I dont want to develo a game engine. I want to develop game by using c++ and OpenGL ES 2.0

Comment: @Megharaj so you are saying you want to use an existing engine? So you might start by looking at what engines are available and running through some tutorials to see how you get on with them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You said you want to use OPENGL ES 2.0, I understand you want develop for an Android or IPhone device.
2. You need read some about matrix, rotation, translations. OpenGl ES doesn't have glrotate and gltranslate methods(and more), but you can develop your own methods method using then OpenGl documentation:
   http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glRotate.xml
   http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glTranslate.xml
3. If you want to use OPENGL for draw, you will need write a vertex and fragment shader
   [What kind of shader for 2D games (ie. Super Mario)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9714443/what-kind-of-shader-for-2d-games-ie-super-mario/9733430#9733430)

A lot of stuff you need, this is only a little piece. I hope this be helpful to you.

Comment: can u please recommend me which game engine must I use to develop 3d game, I have knowledge on OpenGL ES 2.0 amd C. its ok even if C++. please do replay

Comment: for android? for iphone? I only know SIO2 and Unity3D, they aren't free, but there are much more. I cant tell you anything about them, because I haven't used.